# List of algorithms that depend on sorting / ranking / argsorting

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, sorting

I am looking for a list of algorithms that depends on sorting / relative ranking / argsorting, *not* for a list of sorting algorithms.

I want to study and illustrate the importance of fast sorting in other algorithms. I am looking for something rather exhaustive (or at least covering my - not so - niche field: data science). Any idea if that sort of list was formalized somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You probably checked this obvious reference already. I add it just in case: The Art of Computer Programming, Vol III sorting and searching, D. Knuth, Chapter 5, pages 1 to 5 provide an overview of sorting applications. These may lead to other sources discussing related algorithms that depend on sorting. The Huffman encoding algorithm starts with a sort on the character frequencies.